# Tailwind Config is not overriding default value

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to override the `borderColor` inside `tailwind.config.js` after upgrading from `2.2` to `3.0.0`. Here's the implementation:

```
// tailwind.config.js
...
theme: {
        extend: {
            borderColor: ({ theme }) => ({
                ...theme('colors'),
                DEFAULT: theme('colors.gray.300', 'currentColor')
            }),
        }
```

Any idea why? It used to work in 2.2 & lower. Or has the `DEFAULT` variable been removed in Tailwind 3.0?

Comment: Did you try setting the `borderColor` outside the `extend` object?

Comment: Yes, I did. No difference